# Cant display image in Excel file

Tags: php, mysqli, phpexcel

I was able to export all data in excel from mysql database. Problem is, currently printing only image name which is stored in database. But want to show image which is stored in image folder. Please help me ...

Thanks in advance..

```
<?php

  header("Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel");
  header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=product.xls");
  header("Pragma:no-cache");
  header("Expires:0");

  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
  header("Content-type: application/octetstream");
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
 /** Error reporting */
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

  if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
  die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

  /** Include PHPExcel */
  require_once 'classes/PHPExcel.php';
  Include ('config.php');
  $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

  $sql = 'SELECT * from exceloutput';
  $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  if (!$res) {
    die(mysqli_error($conn));
  }
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
  $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
  $col = 0; 
  $row = 1; 
  while($mrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) { 
    $col = 0; 
    foreach($mrow as $key=>$value) { 
        // TODO: Do Something With the Column Name like set the row header. Note this crude code sets it every time. You really just want to do it the first time only.
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 0, $key);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row + 1, $value); 
        $col++; 
    } 
    $row++; 
  }
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

  // Save Excel 2007 file
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="report.xls"');
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
  // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
  // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
  header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
  header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
  header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
  header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');


  exit;
```

Comment: Why are you doing `$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();` and `$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);` twice?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the examples like [05featuredemo.inc.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/05featuredemo.inc.php) or the [PHPExcel documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#add-a-drawing-to-a-worksheet) to see how to add an image to a worksheet.

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('PHPExcel logo');
$objDrawing->setDescription('PHPExcel logo');
$objDrawing->setPath('./images/phpexcel_logo.gif');
$objDrawing->setHeight(36);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('D24');
$objDrawing->setOffsetX(10);
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```

You should always read the documentation first before asking here on StackOverflow.